# Update no Campo TimeField Django 2.0

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django-2.0

Tenho um Model com vários campos, um deles é do tipo TimeField:

```
class Venda(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(u'AÇAIEX', primary_key=True)
    hora_saida = models.TimeField(max_length=6)
```

Para Salvar no sistema o campo funciona beleza, agora quando vai fazer update o campo retorna apenas os minutos e os segundos não trazendo as horas, o banco de dados que uso é mysql:

Exemplo no Banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo no Sistema que traz apenas os minutos e segundos
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foi resolvido acrescentado o código no setting:

```
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = [ '%H:%M', ]
```

Assim ele retorna horas e minutos.